# Declaring a set c++

Tags: c++, set, token

What is wrong with declaring a set here, it is my professors code.

```
set<Token> stmtBeginTokens
{
    Token::IF, Token::ID, Token::WHILE, Token::INPUT,
        Token::OUTPUT, Token::EMPTYSTMT, Token::BREAK,
        Token::RETURN, Token::HALT, Token::NEWLINE
};
```

Later (for Reference):

```
bool isSTMTBegin(Token t)
{
    return stmtBeginTokens.find(t) != stmtBeginTokens.end();
}
```

The error is 1>c:\users\sam\dropbox\compiler project 2\compilerproject2\lex\imp.h(39): error C2473: 'stmtBeginTokens' : looks like a function definition, but there is no parameter list.

My prof uses c++11 and I have the old version, is that the issue? I read the reference but it seemed overly complicated and confusing.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, You should use C++11 and that is an initializer_list which is supported since C++11.

Comment: @MM.: Make that an answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use C++11 to compile it, it uses [`initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list).

```
set<Token> stmtBeginTokens { ...
                           ^ initializer_list (since C++11)
```

If your compiler supports C++11, use `-std=c++11` compile option (gcc).

Comment: Well technically speaking the brace doesn't signify an `initializer_list`, but use of c++11's uniform initialization syntax. It's just a case where an `initializer_list` is implicitely created out of the constructor arguments, since that is (by definition) the best match.

Comment: Visual Studio doesn't have c++11. Do I need to create a vector and push that into a set?

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio do you have? If it doesn't have C++11, yes you can push them into the set.

Comment: @MM. it doesn't matter which version. There is no version (as of the time of writing this) that can handle this construct, as they're all missing `std::initializer_list`...

Comment: @rubenvb: Thanks, I haven't programed in Visual Studio since C++11 and don't know about its issues.